# hit test with for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hittest

i have 10 bricks, whenever my ball hit one of them i want to remove that brick. (brick breaker)

That is what i tried

```
for (int bri=1; bri<11; bri++) {
//  NSObject *brickimg = [NSObject stringWithFormat:@"brick%d", bri];
//  if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, brickimg.frame)) {
//      [UIImageView stringWithFormat:@"brick%d", bri].hidden = YES;
//  }
}
```

and also

```
UIImageView *brickimg = [UIImageView stringWithFormat:@"brick%d", bri];
```

but no chance. 
How is the correct Syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

How about calling `stringWithFormat:` on the correct class, which is `NSString`?

Comment: UIImageView *brickimg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"brick%d", bri];
   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, brickimg.frame)) {
NSLog(@"test");
   }

that is crashes

Comment: Sorry, but I have the impression that you don't know at all what you're doing. If you want a UIImageView you can init one with an image which you retrieve with a name that you construct with stringWithFormat:. But then, this is most probably not what you want to do here anyway, as you want to check against already availably instances.

Comment: your impression quite right. im just trying to get it. 
all i want to do getting avoid writing 10 times CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, brick1.frame) .. 2 .. 3

Comment: I think Eiko was referring to your being clue impaired in the larger sense.  No worries, we all started there.  I'd suggest you (re)read the Objective-C guide provided in the documentation to gain a thorough understanding of Objects, Classes, and Methods.  Then go from there.

Comment: Thanks for your common sense. I'll do that. Actually i'm reading O'really's iPhone Game Development.